# some garbled characters on joomla

Tags: php, nginx, joomla

One day, I got a complaint about articles on Joomla 2.5 became weird and garbled. I found that after some reading on the net that this might be caused by encoding not being utf8. So I did some configurations on php.ini, nginx.conf & my.cnf and managed to get utf8 as output below

```
$ curl -I http://192.168.150.129
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
Date: Thu, 10 Dec 2015 04:33:21 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

mysql> show variables like 'char%';
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                       |
| character_set_connection | utf8                       |
| character_set_database   | utf8                       |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | utf8                       |
| character_set_server     | utf8                       |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
8 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

but I'm still seing Ã‚Â on published articles.

Any tips or hints would be appreciated.

Comment: That's what you get if you send the browser UTF8, but it renders it as `latin1` or similar. So, the header is saying it's UTF8 but the HTML document itself must be overriding that setting.

Comment: You mean, Joomla done that? How do I make sure of that so I can fix it?

Comment: I would look at an article that is exhibiting the behaviour and inspect the `head` element for a `meta charset`. Once you have confirmed the cause, then it simplifies the question.

Comment: I found on page source (Firefox -> Developer -> Page Source) that meta charset already UTF-8 `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`

Comment: Now it became `ÃâÃÂ` after I use iconv on db dump and restore it back with command  `iconv -f 'latin1' -t 'utf-8' db-2015-12-03.sql > db-utf8.sql`

Comment: It may be a stupid question, but could `iconv` have been run on the database before? I mean, if you converted `latin` to `utf` on a database that was already `utf` you might get the symptoms you are seeing. Just a thought.

Comment: any command(s) or methods to verify that iconv has been used on that database?

Comment: After I retored last May's backup of that database, this issue goes away. Definitely something/someone messed with it.